# Why the contents of my website overlap each other on the square shaped window (screen with the equal width & height)?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am a new web designer. This is going to be my second website published on online.
The problem is the web site fits nicely in all screen sized window except square shaped screen. 
As an example [this monitor](http://circuittrade.com/74858-thickbox_default/dell-e173fpf-17-lcd-tft-flat-panel-monitor-p-n-0u4941.jpg) will break down my web contents and force them to sit either on top of each other or one underneath each other.  That becomes a terrible looking look. My assumption is that there is a very tiny error in my code that leads to happen so, but I can’t figure out where is the error.
You may have a look my site [here](http://7seasredovisning.se/) though I will paste my code. 
Please help me.
.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>7Seas Redovisning</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>



<body>

<div id="big_wrapper">



<header id="top_header">
<img src="img_akin/7seas1.jpeg" id="logo" alt="" width="12%" height="12%"/>

<h1><span class="header_name"><span class="seven">7</span>Seas Redovisning</span></h1>



<p>

<span class="mob_tele">Mob: 076-9516926 <br />
Tel: 040-133403</span><br />
info@7seasredovisning.se

</p>

</header>

<nav id="top_menu">

</nav>
<!--

<marquee behavior="alternate">We are coming soon, please check back later.</marquee>
-->

<div class="box_container">
<div class="box">Box 1Box 1Box 1Box 1Box 1Box 1Box 1<br>

Box 1Box 1Box 1Box 1Box 1Box 1Box 1<br>
Box 1Box 1Box 1Box 1Box 1Box 1Box 1<br>
Box 1Box 1Box 1Box 1Box 1Box 1Box 1<br>


</div>
<div class="box">Box 1Box 1Box 1Box 1Box 1Box 1Box 1<br>
Box 1Box 1Box 1Box 1Box 1Box 1Box 1<br>
Box 1Box 1Box 1Box 1Box 1Box 1Box 1<br>
Box 1Box 1Box 1Box 1Box 1Box 1Box 1<br>




</div>
<div class="box">Box 1Box 1Box 1Box 1Box 1Box 1Box 1<br>
Box 1Box 1Box 1Box 1Box 1Box 1Box 1<br>
Box 1Box 1Box 1Box 1Box 1Box 1Box 1<br>
Box 1Box 1Box 1Box 1Box 1Box 1Box 1<br>


</div>

</div>




<div id="new_div"> <!--only the main content-->
<section id="main_section">
<!--
<marquee behavior="alternate">We are coming soon, please check back later.</marquee>
-->

<div class="image_service_list">
<div class="img_wrap">
<img src="img_akin/image_1st_body.jpg"  width="650" height="312" alt=""/>
</div>

<div class="service_list">

<span class="style_number">1.</span> INKOMSTDEKLARATION<br /><br /><br />
<span class="style_number">2.</span> MOMSDEKLARATION<br /><br /><br />
<span class="style_number">3.</span> BOLAGSBILDNING<br /><br /><br />
<span class="style_number">4.</span> EKONOMI KONSLUT<br /><br /><br />
<span class="style_number">5.</span> LÖPANDE BÖKFÖRING

</div>

<div class="service_list">

<span class="style_number">6.</span> BOKSLUT & ÅRSREDOVISNING<br /><br /><br />
<span class="style_number">7.</span> SKATTEDEKLARATION<br /><br /><br />
<span class="style_number">8.</span> LÖNEADMINISTRATION<br /><br /><br />
<span class="style_number">9.</span> FAKTURERING<br /><br /><br />
<span class="style_number">10.</span> ONE MORE

</div>
</div>

</section>

</div>

<footer id="the_footer">

<p class="footer_text"><span id="footer_left">
© 7 seas Redovisning <br />                                         

En del av 7seas Money Transfer KB<br />                 
F-skatt registrerat  <br />                                         
Org, Nr: 969756-4079 <br />   
SEB Företagskonto: 5502-1030132<br />
BG: 102-5006
</span>
</p>


<p class="footer_text">
Besökadress: <a href="https://www.google.se/maps/place/Skomakarebyn+8,+218+41+Bunkeflostrand/@55.5592313,12.9325061,3a,75y,153.78h,90t/data=!3m4!1e1!3m2!1sufqG4dOye4Igl8W2ATJPgg!2e0!4m2!3m1!1s0x4653a718b0946da5:0xd60c6ee131582f21!6m1!1e1" title="See on Google Map">Skomakarebyn 8E<br /> 
218 41 Bunkeflostrand</a><br /> 
Malmö, Sweden <br />  
Follow us on FB <!-- SMARTADDON BEGIN -->
<br />
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
var s=document.createElement('script');s.type='text/javascript';s.async = true;
s.src='http://s1.smartaddon.com/share_addon.js';
var j =document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];j.parentNode.insertBefore(s,j);
})();
</script>

<a href="http://www.smartaddon.com/?share" title="Share Button" onclick="return sa_tellafriend('www.7seasredovisning.se','bookmarks')"><img alt="Share" src="http://s1.smartaddon.com/s8.png" border="0" /></a>

                        <br />Designed & Developed by <a href="http://jabiralfatah.com/" title="Visit my Website">Jabir Al Fatah</a><br />
                        Copyright @ 2014 <a href="http://dhbangladesh.com/"title="Visit DH BANGLADESH">DH BANGLADESH in SWEDEN.</a>

</p>

<p class="footer_text"><span id="footer_right">
Tel: 040-133403<br />
Mob: 076-9516926<br />
e-Mail: info@7seasredovisning.se<br/>
<a href="http://7seasredovisning.se/">www.7seasredovisning.se</a><br/>
<span id="webstat">
<script src="http://stats.webstat.se/assets/stat_isp2.php"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
document.write("<" + "script src=\"http://stats.webstat.se/statCounter.asp?id=38356&size=" + screen.width + "x" + screen.height + "&depth=" + screen.colorDepth + "&referer=" + escape(document.referrer) + "&isp=" + info2+ "\"></" + "script>"); 
-->
</script>
</span>
<!-- Slut WEBSTAT.SE kod -->
</span>
</p>

</footer>

</div>

</body>


</html>
```

.css:

```
*{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}
#top_header h1 {

font:bold 4em Fantasy;

text-align:center;
margin-top:-105px;
margin-right:250px;

color:#006400;
text-shadow:2px 2px 2px orange;

}

.header_name{
margin-left:80px;

}

.seven{
color:orange;
font-size:1.2em;
text-shadow:2px 2px 2px #006400;
}
#top_header p {

margin-top:-100px;

color:#00008B;
float:right;
font-family:Georgia;
margin-right:20px;

}

.mob_tele{
font-size:13.5px;
}

h2{

font:bold 14px Tahoma;
}
header,section,footer,aside,nav,article,hgroup{
display:block;

}
body{
width:100%;
display:-webkit-box;
display:-o-box;
display:-moz-box;
/*
display:-ms-box;
*/
 display:-ms-flexbox;
   -ms-flex-pack:center;
   -ms-flex-align:center;


box-pack:center;
-webkit-box-pack:center;
-moz-box-pack:center;
-webkit-box-pack:center;
-ms-box-pack:center;
-o-box-pack:center;
background-color:#E6E6FA;


}


#big_wrapper{
max-width:1200px;
margin-top:20px;
margin-bottom:15px;


display:-webkit-box;
display:-o-box;
display:-moz-box;
display:-ms-box;
box-orient:vertical;
-webkit-box-orient:vertical;
-moz-box-orient:vertical;
-ms-box-orient:vertical;
box-flex:1;
-webkit-box-flex:1;
-moz-box-flex:1;
-ms-box-flex:1;
background-color:white;
-webkit-box-shadow:  0 0 2px 2px gray;

}


#top_header{

border:3px soild gray;
padding:20px;

}



#logo{
padding-top:20px;
padding-left:5px;

}

#top_menu{
border-top: 6px solid #20B2AA;
border-radius:0px;
box-shadow: 0 0 1.4px 1.4px  #424242;

color:black;
}


#new_div{
display:block;
display:-moz-box;
display:-o-box;
display:-ms-box;
box-orient:horizontal;
-webkit-box-orient:horizontal;
-moz-box-orient:horizontal;
-ms-box-orient:horizontal;


}

#main_section{
/*
border: 1px solid blue;
*/
-webkit-box-flex: 1;
-moz-box-flex: 1;
-ms-box-flex: 1;
-o-box-flex: 1;
margin-top: 20px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
padding: 20px;


}


.service_list{
 display: inline-block;
  float: left;

  margin: 0 10px;


  font-family:Euphemia;

font-weight:bold;

color:green;



}


.style_number{
font: italic 1.2em Georgia, Times, serif;
font-weight:bold;
color:#4169E1;
}


.box {
  display:inline-block;

  margin-top:50px;


  margin-bottom:60px;
  margin-left:55px;
  padding:15px;

  width:280px;

  border: 3px solid gray;
  border-radius:4px;


}
.box_container{

/*
width:1161px;
*/


white-space: nowrap;

}

.img_wrap{
float:right;
position:relative;

}

.img_wrap::before{
   background-image: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 15%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 90%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(to left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 15%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 90%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(to left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 15%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 90%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(to left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 15%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 90%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 15%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 90%);
    content:"\00a0";

    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;

}

#the_footer{

background:#B0C4DE;

border-top:0.5px solid green;


}

.image_service_list{
margin-bottom:500px;


}

.footer_text{

list-style:none;
display:inline-block;

padding:40px;
margin-left:35px;



font-family:Euphemia;
font-size:13px;

}

#the_footer a{
text-decoration: none;

}
#the_footer a:hover{
text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: what is the resolution of square shaped screen.

Comment: I actually can't remember the resolution, but its the same one I gave the link for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm making the assumption that the fitting error you mention is the minimum width your site uses, which causes horizontal scrolling on smaller screens or smaller browserwindows. This also happens when you resize your browserwindow. This is caused by the css on the `.box` which have the three boxes set at 280px width and a pixel margin. I have three different suggestions to fix this.

First option is to make the boxes have flexible widths by using percentages instead of pixels. If you give each for example 30% width and the middle 5% margin on each side you'll get a nice division of three.

Second suggestion is to remove the `white-space: nowrap;` on the `.box_container` to allow the boxes to wrap to newline. This doesn't look very nice though.

Lastly you could use media-queries to change the look on smaller screens. Two articles here:

- [How To Use CSS3 Media Queries To Create a Mobile Version of Your Website - Smashing Magazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/)
- [CSS media queries - Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

This kind of designing for different screens is called responsive webdesign, which is considered good practise as people will visit sites also with phones, tablets and other devices with different screensizes.

Articles on responsive webdesign:

- [Responsive Web Design - A List Apart](http://alistapart.com/article/responsive-web-design)
- [Beginner’s Guide to Responsive Web Design - Treehouse Blog](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-to-responsive-web-design)

*Disclaimer: I haven't recently read each of these articles but I know these sites to be mostly reliable and informative sources*